# Is it possible to use pure Encrypting and Decrypting keys in asymmetric cryptography instead of private and public keys?

Tags: c#, .net, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

Is it possible to use pure Encrypting and Decrypting keys instead of private and public keys? As I know in .Net asymmetric RSA implementation private key `RSAParameters parameters = (new RSACryptoServiceProvider()).ExportParameters(true)` is a superset of public key. And using private key we can both encrypt and decrypt our data. But ***I need key only for decrypting*** data. How to do it?

I experimented on nulling RSAParameters fields, but RSACryptoServiceProvider object can't import such parameters.

Comment: Are you saying you want to use the same key both for encrypting and decrypting?

Comment: I don't think you can. It's possible to generate the public part of an RSA key from the two primes. You might be able to throw away the two primes and just remember the product of the Euler numbers but I don't know what your library stores / uses. Why do you want to do this? If you want to ensure that only Alice and encrypt and only Bob can decode, you might do better by giving them both key pairs and have Alice sign all her messages with her key then encrypt them for Bob: Bob can decrypt but can no longer forge an encrypted message because he can't sign with Alice's key.

Comment: You have a pretty decent mix-up of terms in this question. There is an (important) difference between **decoding/encoding** and **decrypting/encrypting**. Encode is what you do with UTF-8, MP3 and such things. What you are talking about is called **decryption**. Just in case you want to ask Google about it. And you are right in your comment to @Stefan Steinegger's answer: this looks like verifying a signature (it actually *is* veryfying a signature); so I would say it should be possible. No idea about the API though...

Comment: Thank you for remark! I will change Encode to Encrypt and Decode to decrypt in main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, you're solving a problem like this one:

You encrypt some data.  You send it to clients, and want them to be able to decrypt it, but you do *not* want them to be able to encrypt anything, because then they could convince *other* clients that they're you.

Is that close?  Can you tell us what problem you're solving?

For the rest of the folks on the thread, it sounds pretty clear the OP wants a decrypt-only key, instead of the usual encrypt-only public key.

*Edit: the comments are correct in that a private key can't be used to encrypt, but it's not that difficult to generate the public key given the private key.  If you have the private key, you effectively can have both keys.*

*Edit 2: OP, you should probably look into [digital signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature).  You could sign a message (using the private key) and then confirm the signature with the public key, which I think is exactly what you asked for.*

Comment: Something like this. Clients are not humans, they are special facilities. I send commands to them. Of course I can use symmetric cryptography, but it's not so secure

Comment: There is no such thing as a "encrypt or decrypt only key" in public key cryptography. The main reason being that there is no (or no "real") technical or mathematical difference between those two keys. The difference is how you handle the keys. Once you have given away one of them, you call it public key. But *before* you gave it away you could have decided to give the other one away, then that would have become your "public" key... It really does not matter. The only important point is that you can *decrypt* anything you have *encrypted* with the other key **and vice versa!**

Comment: @scherand. In this case I can't understand you. In standard RSA implementation public key is really encrypt-only.

Comment: You can use the public key to encrypt and decrypt, you can only do the opposite though with the private key.

Comment: @SLC: You are mistaken! Standard public key is for encryption only. You can not decrypt by it

Comment: @macropas: No. The source of the confusion is that, when you use a library or such thing, you never get to choose which of the two keys will become your public key and which the private one. But theoretically you **could** choose free (as in beer :)). Once you (or someone else) has decided which of the two keys is named "public" you "only decrypt" with it because you call it "sign" when you encrypt something with it (there are some practical differences but they do not matter for the concept). A signature is nothing but something you "encrypted with your private key" (and hence can only be...

Comment: ...decrypted with your public key). Or the other way around: if something *can be decrypted with your public key, it must have been encrypted with your private key*. Hence you call it "signed".

Comment: Yup signing is what I was referring to

Comment: @scherand It's not true that you can arbitrarily call one of the two keys public and the other private. The public key most likely has a well-known exponent such as 65,537 -- probably the first exponent to guess. You had better know what you are doing when generating keys, before switching their uses. In most cases, it is not difficult to discover the public key, from the private key. So, don't switch them.

Answer (score 1):

For decoding data you need either the public *or* the private key. Depends on how it was encoded.

Stick with the standard patterns, and just be careful *never* to distribute your private key.

---

From your comments (to various answers), you just need signing (of a Hash of your data). It is no use to encrypt data with a key that everybody can have.

There are standard functions and patterns for signing.

Comment: Standard public key is intended for encoding, but I need public key for decoding. And my encoding key must be secret

Comment: Oh, sorry, misunderstood. Yes, this is possible and is essentially how signing works: you decrypt the plaintext with your private key and then someone else can encrypts the result with the public key to get the plaintext back. (Obviously it's the symmetric key you decrypt / encrypt, etc.)

Comment: can you explain more about the situation?  Normally you wouldn't want to do that, because then anybody can decrypt the message since the decoding key is the public key.  Now, in the case of digitally signing something, you'd use your private key and others could verify with your public key, but that's much different than the actual encryption of the data, since you're fine with anyone being able to verify the digital signature :)

Comment: To James Manning. My task looks like digital signing, but I don't need any hash. I need a public key to decrypt arbitrary text and a secret private key to encode it. It's a mirror task for usuall RSA encoding.

Comment: @macropas: RSA is not well suited for large data.

Comment: Data is not so large. Less than 1K

Comment: 1kByte is a lot of 128 bit blocks. Don't do it.

Comment: That's why you generally generate a random symmetric encryption key. You encrypt your data with this symmetric key and encrypt only the symmetric key with the RSA. This way you can even send the same encrypted message to many people with different private keys at once - you can send multiple different encryptions of the symmetric key at once along with a single symmetrically-encrypted message. However you then need individual random values to add / xor to the symmetric key for each recipient so that you don't ever RSA-encrypt the same number twice (else Chinese Remainder Theorem attack).

Comment: @Rup, normally yes. But here a signature is all that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the private key for decrypting and the public key for encrypting.

The receiver (decrypter) sends it's public key to the sender (encrypter). So everyone can send messages, only the receiver can read them. It this what you need?

If you need to make sure that the message come from a certain sender, it needs to add a signature by using its own private key. The receiver can verify this by using the senders public key.

Comment: No, I need the private key for encoding my arbitrary messages and my users must have my open key for decoding my messages. I understand, it's a strange task looks like digital signing, but I can't use RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter/Deformatter for it.

Comment: I don't really understand why it is not working like this. You probably need to combine encoding and signing, as described in my answer. I agree, it gets complicated because of that. But you should solve all the problems I can think of with that.

Comment: If I read it right, you're suggesting that every recipient has their own public/private key pair and he individually encrypts the message to all of them (or at least a symmetric key). I don't think he wants it to work like that.

Comment: @Rup: only if he wants to send individual messages to them which another can't read. I actually don't know what he wants. But if he wants this kind of security, he needs such a mechanism.

Comment: Stefan, the OP want to send (public) messages others can't _fake_.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that the private key-holder cannot encrypt something such that the result is indistinguishable from a message sent by the public key-holder, then you could simply double-wrap your data.

Simply have two key-pairs.

Side A gets the private key of key-pair 1, and the public key of key-pair 2.
Side B gets the public key of key-pair 1, and the private key of key-pair 2.

Side B sends his/her/its message by first encrypting it with the public key of key-pair 1, and then the private key of key-pair 2.

Side A decrypts the result using the public key of key-pair 2, and the private key of key-pair 1 (in that order).

Side A can generate the public key of key-pair 1, but cannot generate the private key of key-pair 2, so side A cannot generate a valid message.

The inverse works in the other direction.

Down-side:  If you have a central person (or server) that every other person (or computer) is communicating with, each party needs their own private key, and they need to share the corresponding public key with the central person (or server) they are communicating with.

Comment: You can not decrypt message using public key in asymmetric ciphering. Your algorithm is wrong

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA#Signing_messages <-- This description sounds a LOT like encrypting the hash with the private key, and decrypting it with the public key.  Just saying that you can use a symmetric key just as easily as a hash in the described situation.